# how to debug objects that located on the heap?(eclipse-java)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm trying to debug classes that seat on a jar and i cant "see" the objects in display option!

Someone told me that reason can be that objects in this class are located on the heap and not  on the stack.

How can I access these objects in debug mode?

Answer (score 1):

You don't debug objects or classes. You debug methods. Put a breakpoint inside a method of the object you want to debug, and you'll be able to inspect the contents of this object when this method is called.

If you have an object A containing a collection of objects B, put a breakpoint in a method of A, and you'll be able to inspect its collection of Bs when this method is called.

But you can't just start in debug and see all the objects on the heap. It could be very difficult to identify the one you're looking for.

Comment: I fear the OP wants to debug classes for which the source is not available in his/her workspace? @user986180: true?

Comment: @user986180: Yes, you're right, that's the user's problem. He doesn't need directions on how to add and use a breakpoint

Comment: You are right . I know how to locate breakpoints.. The problem is indeed that the classes are not available in my workspace..  i'm trying to debug code that seat in the jar without access to source code. I'il be glad for you help

Comment: And just for clarity, debug is not just for inside methods. You can also set debug breakpoints inside a constructo or a static initializer block.

Answer (score 1):

First off you're jumbling some notions. Objects instances are allocated on what's called Heap memory, aka on the heap. Method calls (on those instances) are placed in the stack memory space, aka on the stack. Look up the notions of heap and stack memory in the Java (and general OOP) jargon to get a better idea.

Second, when you add a break-point, debug your program in Eclipse, and that breakpoint is hit by the execution, and the Eclipse Debug perspective is shown, there's multiple aspects that you should be aware of:

- you can see the current instance's global (class level) fields and their values (in the upper right corner of your view, in the "variables" tab. You can also see the variables+values of those variables local to the method you are debugging.
- you can also see the stack (in the upper right corner of the view), aka the chain of methods placed in the stack space that were called prior to the current method where the debugger stopped.
- when you debug one of your own classes, you'll clearly see at what point in the code you are (that's the big window in the lower part of the view) - that's because the source code of that class is available to Eclipse. However if you continue your debugging, you might stumble upon a method call that goes into the instance of a class who's source code you don't have (like if your project uses some external jar, and your current method call uses some method of some instance of a class in that external jar). At this point Eclipse can no longer show you the "pretty" code in the lower part of the view, it just shows you some jumble (it's the compiled byte code) and also a button that lets you attach (if available) the sources of tha external jar, so that it can be displayed properly. IF you use that "attach sources" button you can browse around and select the sources of your jar. For most (at least the good ones) jar libraries, you also get a separate jar with the sources, which you should download and attach to the actual jar in order to be able to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

For the classes for which you don't have code , you can use 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/ which will decompile the class file and show u the code. You can debug , see variables values , control flow but can't make any edits.

One more option is to attach source archive, for the jar which you need to debug. But in this case too u can't make edits.

Mostly you will not be making changes in third party jars. In case its really necessary get the source code if its available.

One more way is once class is decompiled, copy the content in a java file under same path in your project. Now this class will be picked from u r code instead of jar and **you can also 
make changes**